# replacing an input field's display

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to write a lightweight html/javascript widget which lets me colour each character as it is entered. I was thinking that the way to do it would be to have an input field that reacted to events, but whose actual display was overlaid by an html div that reads the input field's value, highlights it, and writes it out. Is this the recommended way to do things? Is there a library out there that already implements this, and takes care of any fiddly details I might not have thought of?

edit: searching for ways to implement cronoklee's contentEditable idea brought up this nice article: http://perplexed.co.uk/993_contenteditable_cross_browser_wysiwyg.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be of interest:
http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#contenteditable

I would probably set up a contenteditable div, and call a javascript function on keypress that wraps the last inputted character in styled span tags. If you need to submit the inputted data, set up a input type='hidden' and populate that on keypress. No need to overlay one on the other!

EDIT: 
I just realised (months later!) that you can simply use div.textContent to get the content of the input. That will just show the text without styling so no need for that extra input field to catch characters.

Comment: that sounds a bit too powerful - i don't want to let the user enter arbitrary html in my textfield, i want my own callback functions to highlight his text as he enters or modifies it.

Comment: Well using the system I described above you could filter the input to only characters you specify. You could even disable editing altogether and have the div populated by javascript as the user types. This means they would not see a caret which is a usability issue.

Comment: hm - okay, i see where you're going with that. nice idea, and i get arbitrary styling of the div for free.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a syntax highlighter/editor,  is really good. There's a demo: http://ajaxorg.github.com/ace/build/editor.html

Comment: again, too heavy - all i want is coloured text via some callbacks, not a full fledged editor or even a lexer.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a lot of trouble, for not much gain. Personally I like the way stackoverflow does it, using a textarea and onblur they apply the highlighting to a preview.

Comment: this is for an online word game; there needs to be, e.g., realtime feedback if the user has started typing something invalid (text should turn red letter by letter) as well as for some other global conditions (so you could type in something and a different part of the string would colour itself)